# Classes and inheritance in React

Tags: reactjs

I am new to programming and JS/React.

React philosophy favors Composition over Inheritance, and yet the official React examples use "classes which extend" ...

Is there a contradiction? Is there a way to rewrite this without classes?

Example:

```
class Square extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <button className="square">
        {this.props.value}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

From here: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your react components must extend the `React.Component` class which contains the basic for all components. The react philosophy only discourage the fact that a component extends another component.

There is anyway a way to prevent using classes, using functions and, if needed, hooks:

```js
const Square = ({value}) => (
  <button className="square">
    {value}
  </button>
);
```

See: https://en.reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html

Comment: Thanks. I see also the magic word "this" disappears this away. Can its absence have any significance?

Comment: The word `this` references the current instance of the class. Here, we are using functions and have no class, so no `this`.

Answer (score 0):

> Blockquote
>
> `props(){ Square : anytype } render() { return ( const Square =this.props; <button className="square"> {Square } </button> ); }`